# I want to make my Icons Automatically go to next Row in flutter if previous row gets completrly filled with icons

Tags: flutter

I am building a quiz app using Dart flutter in that some questions will get displayed and users have to click on true or false buttons depending upon question is right or wrong. To tell users that they are right or wrong icon (✓ or ✘) will get displayed in bottom row every time they choose answer by clicking on either of the button. But in flutter if row gets completely filled i got error
value: Not in inclusive range. So i want that icon should automatically go to next row.

Heres the short code which i tried:

List  scorekeeper = [];

void score(bool userpickedanswer) {

```
setState((){
if (userpickedanswer == correctanswer) {
  scorekeeper.add(Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.green,));
}
else {
  scorekeeper.add(Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.red,));
}
```

}

Row {
childeren : scorekeeper

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Wrap` widget instead of the `Row` widget and when the line of icon fills to the end the `Wrap` widget makes another line **automatically**

Use the code like this:

```
Wrap(
    children: scorekeeper,
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `wrap` instead of a `row`. It prevents overflow by displaying the items depending on the available space:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html